# Verify email before authenticating using Azure B2C auth service

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, openid, azure-ad-b2c

**Situation**

I want to use Azure B2C auth service for my web app. However, I want the admins of the app to restrict access to certain emails or domains e.g. a whitelist as follows:

- tom1@abc.com
- tom2@def.com
- *@alphabet.com

So only the top two emails and anyone else with an email ending in "alphabet.com" can access the site.

**Problem**

I have everything implemented and it's working correctly, however I'm struggling to get the email address of the authenticated user to do the whitelist check during the signon/signin process. The AuthenticationTicket has all the claims requested (FirstName, LastName, Name, Object Identifer etc.), but the email is not present (It has been setup in Azure B2C as a claim).

How can I access the email and is this the right place to be checking?

Code in `Startup.App.cs`

```
private OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions CreateOptionsFromPolicy(string policy)
{
    return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // For each policy, give OWIN the policy-specific metadata address, and
        // set the authentication type to the id of the policy
        MetadataAddress = String.Format(aadInstance, tenant, policy),
        AuthenticationType = policy,

        // These are standard OpenID Connect parameters, with values pulled from web.config
        ClientId = clientId,
        RedirectUri = redirectUri,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
        {
            AuthenticationFailed = AuthenticationFailed,
            AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
            {
                // no claims present here
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
            SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
            {
                // no claims present here
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
            SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
            {
                // print all claims - quite a few except email :( Is this where this check should be done?
                foreach (var claim in context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(claim.Value);
                }
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            },
        },
        Scope = "openid",
        ResponseType = "id_token",

        // This piece is optional - it is used for displaying the user's name in the navigation bar.
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType  = "name"
        },
    };
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If it's a B2C tenant, did you select "emails" as one of the Application Claims in the B2C Admin portal?

Answer (score 1):

**You must specify the claims you want to be sent to your application in the policy in the 'Select application claims' blade.**

The blade where you can configure this is

*Azure AD B2C Settings > Settings > Sign-up or sign-in policies > Application Claims*

You should make sure you've got `email` selected as per the screenshot below.

[image: Select application claims]